# Android EditText click event triggering on second time

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` inside a `RelativeLayout` which is child of a `ScrollView`. `RelativeLayout` has a list of `EditText`. My problem is `EditText` is triggering Click Event on second time click.

I have used `android:focusable="true"`  `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` attributes but no luck.

I have added code. Actually, I am opening a DatePickerDialog on EditText Click event. That's why I had disabled editable attribute. But click event is triggering on second click and DatePickerDialog is showed.

```
            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/eight"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white_bg"
                android:id="@+id/nine"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/lossDate"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:background="@drawable/transparent"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_calendar"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:hint=" Date Of Loss (Required)" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/lossDateCancel"
                    android:layout_height="23dp"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_cancel"
                    android:layout_width="23dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have u tried `android:focusable="false"`

Comment: @NileshRathod Yes I have tried but no luck.

Comment: share your code with question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `clickable=false` and `focusable=false`

```
 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/lossDate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:editable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:background="@drawable/transparent"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_calendar"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:hint=" Date Of Loss (Required)" />
```